# Software for profiling people

Tags: windows, contact-manager, crm

I'm looking for a software which is kind of like an address book, but a little more complex than that. You should be able to write a whole profile of the specific person into a template.

I tried Libreoffice Base and some address book software, but I'm looking for something more specific, like a CRM but not really for employees.

Would be great if it was free / Open Source.

I tried a lot of CRMs (e.g. suitecrm.com or zurmo.org or splendidcrm.com or opencrx.org). The problem is that I want more features on profiling, let's say a field for when I first met that person, what his secrets are, and so on. Maybe a facebook-like thing? It's not to analyse that person, it's more a memory aid because of my dementia.

Comment: If you use something like the open source version of sugarcrm, and maybe suitecrm since it is a derivative, you can add extra fields for this purpose. Of course it means you have to maintain the installation yourself locally or online.

Answer (score 2):

If you still haven't found anything to suit your need, have a look at Simitless. It enables you to design your app (in your case, a personal CRM of sorts) from readily available modules to track what you want and how you want it.

You can collect information about your contacts, their email, when you met them, their favorite movie, when you talked to them last and so on as well as upload photos, etc.

Your app is always accessible online, it can be shared with whoever you want (or not shared, your choice), it is private and secure. I assume that for your need it would be free as I don't think you'll have industrial amounts of data to track :). And, you can import and export data.

It sounds like it can suit your need, from the way I understood your problem. Check it out.

**Full disclosure: I am part of the startup that designed that platform.** We just launched recently, still in beta. If you want to try it out and need some help, I can definitely give you a hand. Just get in touch. (If you want to quickly try it out, there is a template for [Family Address Book](https://simitless.com/en/templates?or=st&preview=templates-family-address-book) that might be a good basis to start out your own app. Here is a quick preview:

[image]

Click the eye icon to preview the template with "dummy data". And, of course, you can modify the template to your heart's desire.) It might be just what you are looking for. And let me know how it goes, if you decide to give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

[Monica](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52744/app-to-keep-notes-about-people/52747#52747) is aslo worth looking at. I has already been described on the SE link. It can be installed locally or on the internet. It also has an android interface.