# App to keep notes about people

Tags: android, note-taking

I'm looking for an Android app which will allow you to import specific people from contacts with pictures or profile pictures and have a set of organized systematic notes on each person with entries such as likes, dislikes, family situation, payment details, if these people are clients, etc., and you can build your own list and back it up to Google Drive.

Thanks.

Comment: Not *exactly* what you asked for (hence no answer but just a hint), but coming pretty close: take a look at my list of [Call Notes](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_917) apps (though most of them are indeed just supporting a simple text field). But then, [DejaOffice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.companionlink.clusbsync) could meet your needs, offering a.o. "custom fields" for contacts. I haven't tried it, but it's well rated and contains no trackers (let me know if this one fits and I should make it an answer).

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [monicahq](https://monicahq.com) - personal relationship manager webapp:

> Monica is an open-source web application to organize the interactions with your loved ones. We call it a PRM, or Personal Relationship Management. Think of it as a CRM (a popular tool used by sales teams in the corporate world) for your friends or family. This is what it currently looks like:
>   [image]

There's also an Android app [chandler](https://github.com/monicahq/chandler) That is still in development but already supports bunch of features:

> Chandler is Monica's official mobile app. Monica is an open source personal relationship manager available as a web application. While the web app has many features, the mobile application currently has a limited set of features. It lets you read your data from your web account.

It's also FLOSS (GPLv3) on Github: https://github.com/monicahq/monica
As well as on Patreon: https://www.patreon.com/monicahq

Comment: I'm tempted to mark that "NAA" (not an answer). Why? Look what OP asked for: "I'm looking for an **Android app"** (I wouldn't recommend trusting some website with sensitive data on my contacts either).

Comment: @Izzy monica does offer an android app as well I forgot to include that, but in all fairness webapp is hardly different from current android apps which are just wrappers around webapps anyway.

Comment: @Izzy Regarding security it's a floss project and you are welcome to fire up an instance of your own instance - it hardly requires any resources; to imply that android app of all things would be more secure is laughable to say the least.

Comment: I did not say an Android app would be more secure – but that the OP asked specifically for such (i.e. something to use on-device), and not for a web app. A web app would need a web server, which OP might not have.